# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos

I am having trouble installing Rails on Cent OS. I tried the following command

```
gem install rails --source http://rubygems.org
```

but I get the error

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I see the rails gem in 'gem search' and the right path in 'gem sources'

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?  Can you show us the output of `gem sources`?

Comment: ruby 1.8.7, gem 1.3.7

Comment: *** CURRENT SOURCES ***

 http://rubygems.org/

Comment: Try running `gem sources -a https://rubygems.org`, then attempt to install rails again.

Comment: still same error unfortunately

Comment: Maybe it's a permission problem, are you installing as root?

Comment: yes, i'm installing as the root user. should I not do that?

Comment: Are you even able to reach rubygems.org from the server?

Comment: Yes, when I do "curl rubygems.org" I get "<html><body>You are being <a href="https://rubygems.org/">redirected</a>.</body></html>"

Comment: are you deploying? use heroku. want a cheaper alternative?, use digital ocean, it comes with ready to work images.